# How are matrices stored in memory?

Tags: memory, matrix, compression, jpeg

Note - may be more related to computer organization than software, not sure.

I'm trying to understand something related to data compression, say for jpeg photos. Essentially a very dense matrix is converted (via discrete cosine transforms) into a much more sparse matrix. Supposedly it is this sparse matrix that is stored. Take a look at this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Comparing the original 8x8 sub-block image example to matrix "B", which is transformed to have overall lower magnitude values and much more zeros throughout. How is matrix B stored such that it saves much more memory over the original matrix?

The original matrix clearly needs 8x8 (number of entries) x 8 bits/entry since values can range randomly from 0 to 255. OK, so I think it's pretty clear we need 64 bytes of memory for this. Matrix B on the other hand, hmmm. Best case scenario I can think of is that values range from -26 to +5, so at most an entry (like -26) needs 6 bits (5 bits to form 26, 1 bit for sign I guess). So then you could store 8x8x6 bits = 48 bytes.

The other possibility I see is that the matrix is stored in a "zig zag" order from the top left. Then we can specify a start and an end address and just keep storing along the diagonals until we're only left with zeros. Let's say it's a 32-bit machine; then 2 addresses (start + end) will constitute 8 bytes; for the other non-zero entries at 6 bits each, say, we have to go along almost all the top diagonals to store a sum of 28 elements. In total this scheme would take 29 bytes.

To summarize my question: if JPEG and other image encoders are claiming to save space by using algorithms to make the image matrix less dense, how is this extra space being realized in my hard disk?

Cheers

Comment: The very next section of the Wikipedia article, “Entropy coding”, is about just that. You might want to review that section and ask about what you don't understand.

Comment: OK so it is actually going to be stored in that zig-zag pattern. Now my question would 8 bits per entry still be used or could we move to down to say 6?

Comment: Huffman coding can handle a zig-zag patterns as it depends on the frequency of an occurrence, not that they are consecutive.

Comment: Or are you referring to the prefix codes as zig-zag? In that case you should know that high frequency occurrences have shorter prefix codes and is stored using fewer number of bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in "Entropy coding" a zig-zag pattern is used, together with RLE which will already reduce size for many cases. However, as far as I know the DCT isn't giving a sparse matrix per se. But it usually enhances the entropy of the matrix. This is the point where the compressen becomes lossy: The intput matrix is transferred with DCT, then the values are quantizised and then the huffman-encoding is used.

Answer (score 2):

The dct needs to be accompanied with other compression schemes that take advantage of the zeros/high frequency occurrences. A simple example is run length encoding.

JPEG uses a variant of Huffman coding.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple compression would take advantage of repeated sequences of symbols (zeros). A matrix in memory may look like this (suppose in dec system)

```
0000000000000100000000000210000000000004301000300000000004
```

After compression it may look like this

```
(0,13)1(0,11)21(0,12)43010003(0,11)4
(Symbol,Count)...
```

Answer (score 1):

As my under stand, JPEG on only compress, it also drop data. After the 8x8 block transfer to frequent domain, it drop the in-significant (high-frequent) data, which means it only has to save the significant 6x6 or even 4x4 data. That it can has higher compress rate then non-lost method (like gif)